# Nothing is working in my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, power-management, shutdown

I force shut down my laptop then nothing is working, the power key is also not working properly neither is the keyboard.

When I press power key my screen loads to grub menu then after 25s it's taking me to the log in screen but I am unable to do anything and it's also very difficult to boot or shut down my laptop.

Can someone help me?

Comment: you need to add more information to your question,did it work before? when/how did this happen? any error messages? what type of laptop is it(brand+name),have you tried to use the tools found in grub?